# Removing and reinserting a DOM element onclick

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild, removechild

I recently wrote a script in which I needed an element to move to the top when it was clicked on. I used, and have been using for years, the following code in the onclick function:

```
this.parentNode.appendChild(this.parentNode.removeChild(this));
```

The script wasn't working, and so I messed around with the code, trying things I'd never done before in an effort to fix it. I thought the problem might lie in this line of code. Actually, it turned out to have nothing to do with it, but while I was tinkering around, I noticed that the following code seems to perform the same function.

```
this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
```

As far as I can tell, there is no difference. The former feels "better" to me, but I can't really say why. Is there an actual difference? If not, I'll start using the latter and save eighteen characters :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>`this` is not a child of `this`.

You need to remove the child from the parent node.</strike>

However, `appendChild` will [implicitly remove the node from any existing parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) (elements cannot have multiple parents):

> If the node already exists it is removed from current parent node, then added to new parent node.

Comment: Sorry, of course you are right. I left out a "parentNode" when I posted. I've edited the question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the answer. I've been a lurker here for years, and this was the first time I had to ask a question myself. This really is a fantastic site. I'm also incredibly impressed with the speed with which it was answered. Thank you!